# Autolayout ignores navigationbar

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, storyboard, autolayout

I have the following `storyboard` view.
[image]

But this gives me the following view when I run it.

[image]

Could somebody tell me why this view is pushed so far below the `navigationbar`. You can see that my `Top Space to: Top Layout is 49.` But when I change it to 5 for example my button gets bigger, what is very strange because I've set `height equals to 30`.

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing all of the other constraints for that view controller.  You do have a red circle to the right of the view controller's name.  I'd start by clicking on that and see what the errors are.

Comment: @user3386109 even if I solve all the problems, it still not working.

Comment: Tick underTopBar checkBox in Attribute inspector of the storyBoard

Comment: The top layout guide height is 64 with a status bar and a navigation bar. That puts the button at 113 if the top constraint is 49. Changing the top constraint to 5 puts the top of the button at 69, but the bottom of the button is still stuck to the other view by the `Bottom Space to: View Equals: 3` constraint. So one of the three constraints (top-to-guide, height, bottom-to-view) has to be ignored. Evidently autolayout ignores the height and stretches the button. If you delete the bottom-to-view constraint and set the top constraint to 5, then at least the button will be at the right place...